# Where to find the $ symbol?

Tags: keyboard

I am using a Lumia 520. I want to send a message to my friend and that message should include the $ symbol, but I can't find it. Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're probably using a keyboard other than US English. To get the $ sign, switch to symbols by tapping on the <kbd>&123</kbd> button in the lower left corner, then tap and hold on the button corresponding to your local currency to get a list of alternative currency symbols. The $ sign should be listed there.

For instance, with the UK English layout, I need to tap and hold on the <kbd>£</kbd> button:

[image]